# Python import from local folder using vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code and a conda venv. I have created a folder called "project" and in the folder I have 3 sub folders "helper", "function", "function2". Now I have a helper_function.py in folder "helper" where I have defined several functions and I want to import them in my function code where I have a main.py.

```
project/
    helper/
        __init__.py
        helper_function.py
    function/
        __init__.py
        main.py
    function2/
        __init__.py
```

I'm always receiving the error:

```
from helper.helper_function import date_conf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'
```

I have already created a blank `__init__.py` in the helper folder but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add the following code above the import statement:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

[image]

**If you don't want to modify the code, you can also use the following method：**

- Add the `.env` file in the workspace.

*Note that the file name only has an extension. If it is modified, additional settings are required.*

`.env` file:

```
PYTHONPATH = "E:\\Desktop\\project"
```

- Add the following configuration in ***launch.json***

```json
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "E:\\Desktop\\project"
            }
```

***Both of the above need to execute the script in debug mode.***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 possibilities:

- create a setup.py, run and install you package
- modify your PYTHONPATH in VSCode settings or shell session
- update your sys.path before imports

If you're using VSCode, the simplest is probably to update your PYTHONPATH in settings, assuming you have a linux terminal:

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {"PYTHONPATH": "${PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}/helper:${workspaceFolder}/function:${workspaceFolder}/function2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

helper directory must be same level as "main.py" (considering your current working directory is where main.py located).

i suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/9099310) to get familiar with relative and absolute imports.